# Particular form of Asymptotic solution to ODEs

Tags: asymptotics

I am currently reading Heisenberg's PhD [thesis](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=ufl1.ark:/13960/t0tq6vw2q&view=1up&seq=7). There is a common technique in fluid dynamics which keeps cropping up and I can never get my head around.

The equation of interest is the Orr-Sommerfeld equation

$(\phi '' - \alpha^{2}\phi)(w-c) - \phi w'' = \frac{i}{\alpha R}(\phi'''' - 2\alpha^2 \phi '' + \alpha^4 \phi )$

for which we seek an asymptotic representation of the form

$\phi =  e^{\int g dy}, \quad g = \sqrt{\alpha R}g_{0} + g_{1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha R}}g_{2} + ...$

The questions is;

Why is it in this particular form and not some other powers, say,

$\phi =  e^{\int g dy}, \quad g = g_{0} + \frac{1}{\alpha R}g_{1} + \frac{1}{(\alpha R)^2}g_{2} + ...$

??

Comment: Look at Carl Bender's lecture 08 on YouTube

Comment: You need to find the correct scaling of the equation (asymptotics) to 'motivate' what form the solution might take.